# Type mismatch error when trying to declare new vector

Tags: scala, class, declaration

I am trying to create a new vector of class type Vec2(x:Double, y:Double) program is unable to find x and y and returns a mismatch error.

When trying to declare x and y separately I am met with an error "Expression of type (Double, Double) does not conform to expected type Vec2.

```scala
Vec2(x:Double, y:Double)
```

```
val sum:Vec2 = (x:Double , y:Double)
```

Wanting to use the sum vector in the program but am unable to declare it.

Comment: `val sum = Vec2(x, y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here:

```
val sum:Vec2 = (x:Double , y:Double)
```

Firstly, you don't need to specify the types of the values here, so it could be

```
val sum: Vec2 = (x, y)
```

Secondly, the value `(x, y)` is a tuple and there is no automatic mechanism for creating classes from tuples. So you need to specify the class explicitly:

```
val sum:Vec2 = Vec2(x, y)
```

Finally, the type of `sum` is obvious from this statement, so it can be omitted:

```
val sum = Vec2(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am only new to Scala so your detailed answer has helped me tremendously.

Comment: @Barkley101 if Tim's answer helped you, consider up-voting and / or accepting it as the correct answer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).